# how to wrap each case with a div?

Tags: php

I needed to use **switch case** for some reason. Now I am unable to wrap each case with `ul`.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    switch ($value->myvar) {
        case '11':
            echo '<li>' . $value->myvar . '</li>';
            break;

        case '12':
            echo '<li>' . $value->myvar . '</li>';
            break;

        case '13':
            echo '<li>' . $value->myvar . '</li>';
            break;

        default:
            echo 'default';
            break;
    }
}
```

This results:

```
<li>11</li>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
<li>12</li>
<li>13</li>
<li>13</li>
<li>13</li>
```

If I wrap with ul in each case then I get each single list wrapped inside ul. So, how can I wrap that would result like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>11</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>13</li>
</ul>
```

May be there is alternative instead of using switch case. I would also love to get answer which would be as expected as my desired lists would be rendered.

Comment: What's the purpose of the switch statement there? Can't you just restructure your array beforehand?

Comment: I want to loop results like in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have three different variable and echo them after the loop.

```
$ul11 = "<ul>";
$ul12 = "<ul>";
$ul13 = "<ul>";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  switch ($value->myvar) {
    case '11':
       $ul11.='<li>' . $value->myvar . '</li>';
        break;

    case '12':
        $ul12.='<li>' . $value->myvar . '</li>';
        break;

    case '13':
        $ul13.='<li>' . $value->myvar . '</li>';
        break;

    default:
        echo 'default';
        break;
   }
}
$ul11.="</ul>";
$ul12.="</ul>";
$ul13.="</ul>";

echo $ul11;
echo $ul12;
echo $ul13;
```

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Oh! that was so simple. I just forget.... what a silly I am... was asking useless question.

Comment: Haha it happens :)